# how do i write a function that loads a file and upsates the file widget with the words from the file in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget

### Required Functions

There are two required functions.

#### The `update_words` Function

The `update_words` function takes one argument, `filename`, the name of a Mad Lib file. The function loads the file and updates the three `wordtype` widgets with the word types from the file. It should also clear the current values in the `wordtype` widgets. The function should use a global variable called `template` to store the Mad Lib template. The `template` variable will be needed by the `do_madlib` function.

- Function: `update_words` - Update the word types after loading a Mad Lib file.
- Arguments:

  - `filename` - The name of the Mad Lib file
- Returns: None

#### The `do_madlib` Function

The `do_madlib` function takes three arguments `word1`, `word2` and `word3` and uses the global `template` variable to complete the Mad Lib.

- Function: `do_madlib` - Complete the Mad Lib
- Arguments:

  - `word1` `(str)`: The first word
  - `word2` `(str)`: The second word
  - `word3` `(str)`: The thirdword
- Returns: (string or HTML) The completed Mad Lib

### Helpful Hints

#### Using Global Variables

A global variable, like `template`, can be used across functions as long as the functions define it as `global`. In the example the `message` variable is shared between the funcitons and other code:

```py
def fun_a():
    global message
    message = "Hello World!"
    
def fun_b():
    global message
    print(message)
    
fun_a()
fun_b()
message = "Global!"
fun_b()
```

Run this code in the debugger to make sure you understand it.

#### Updating Widgets

Widgets have a `value` and a `description`. Changing them in Python code updates the widget. For example, you can change the first word type to "noun" by running the code:

```py
type1_widget.description = "noun"
```

You can change the value in the box by running the code:

```py
type1_widget.value = "bird"
```

### Requirements

1. Your program must have the required docstrings
2. Changing the file pulldown updates the `description` of the type widgets.
3. Entering values into the type widgets updates the output.

### **This is the code he has written, now i have to write a code that will go with his program.**

```
import pathlib
from p4e.widgets import bind
import ipywidgets

file_widget = ipywidgets.Dropdown(description="File:", options=list(sorted((pathlib.Path('.').glob('madlib*.txt')))))
type1_widget = ipywidgets.Text(description="type1")
type2_widget = ipywidgets.Text(description="type2")
type3_widget = ipywidgets.Text(description="type3")

bind('update_words', {'filename': file_widget})
display(file_widget, type1_widget, type2_widget, type3_widget, 
    bind('do_madlib', {'word1': type1_widget, 'word2': type2_widget, 'word3': type3_widget})
)
```

I am really bad at understanding what he is trying to say apparently.
so this is all i have so far. and i am not sure what to do from there...

""" CIS 15 """

def update_words (filename):
"""update words"""
filename =

```
return
```

def do_madlib (word1, word2, word3):
"""madlibs"""
filehandle = open("madlib1.txt")
filehandle
return